# How to add text formatting like superscript or subscript to a label in a Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, label, shinydashboard

I've built an app with shinydashboard and would like to format correctly some of the input labels.
For example, I have a numeric input like this:

```
numericInput("input_a", "Label (unit = m2)", value = 1)
```

I cannot find how to edit the `m2` to be `m²`.

I have tried to use the `expression` function, without success:

```
expression(Label~(unit~=~m^2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two option -

1. You can copy paste the superscript directly into your text.
2. Use `tags$sup`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage({
  fluidRow(
           column(6, numericInput("input_a", "Label (unit = m²)", value = 1)), 
           column(6, numericInput("input_b", HTML(paste0("Label (unit = m",tags$sup("2"), ')')), value = 1))
           )  
})
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]